# Altering content

Tags: mysql

I am trying to change the value of Null from Yes to No where Field equals content (see below)

[image]

with the following code

```
UPDATE pages SET Null = 'yes' WHERE field = 'content';
```

but I keep getting the following error message

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; ...

I've also tried

> ALTER pages CHANGE Null='no' where field = 'content';

but I got the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no column called `Null` in your database...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean to do:

```
ALTER TABLE pages
  MODIFY COLUMN content text NOT NULL ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to alter table to set whether it can be set null or not. So use something like this

```
 ALTER TABLE pages CHANGE content content text NOT NULL;
```

or

```
 ALTER TABLE pages CHANGE visible visible tinyint(1);
```

You can also use MODIFY to change a column's type without renaming it:

```
ALTER TABLE pages MODIFY visible tinyint(1);
```

Comment: This is amazing, ALTER TABLE pages CHANGE content content text NOT NULL; I never would have though of it. How does the following syntax work: "content content text"?